# If you have reciprocal linking sites, and 1 site removes the link to the other does that site now get the befit / value of the link?

Tags: google, links

If site A links to site B, and then Site B links back to Site A. This will create a reciprocal link and neither site will get the value of each others links.

If site B then removes the link to site A will it then gain back the full value of the link it has from site A ? Or once a link is reciprocal is it always seen in googles eyes as reciprocal ?

Does anyone have any proof / quotes on this ?

Comment: Links are not equal nor do they operate within a vacuum. Here are a few of my answers that speak to link value within them: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84217/how-to-tell-google-to-rank-a-child-page-of-similar-content-higher-than-parent/84233#84233 http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18643/is-link-building-a-white-hat-seo-activity/86906#86906 It is not like passing coins of value back and forth. While how links are valued is rather simple, what happens once implemented gets rather complex. This is because the link value calculations are recursive.