# Implement SEO for new domain suppressing the other

Tags: seo, domains, keywords

I have an existing domain say **www.existingdomain.com** which shows up on top for a keyword say **domain**.

But now I want to have a new domain say **www.newdomain.com** appear on top in google search for same above keyword that is **domain**, such that the old domain URL appears in the search result but in lower order.

Need help in uderstanding how to achieve this

Comment: Are you willing to redirect the old domain to the new one?

Comment: If SEO of `newdomain.com` is better then `exisingdomain.com`, then you can achieve your goal. Here is [similar question but it's about two pages](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/84217/58259). But the answer is same.

Comment: If you want to have your "newdomain.com" appear on top of GG search for the same keyword "domain" then you need to try hard **to do SEO better** than you did for existingdomain

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Ideally it must be like that to avoid duplicate for Google ranking but unfortunately, we will be continuing with old domain for some time and then we will do the 301 permanent redirect.. So meanwhile we will go with both

Comment: @Goyllo that make sense

Comment: @Peter Thanks Man, but that was sarcastic :P